# Laravel / PHP - Embedding a Youtube video into an array of images

Tags: php, laravel, youtube

I'm pretty new to PHP and Laravel, and I've got this landing page which shows images on the page body.

My client wants to add a Youtube video instead of one of the images, and I'm not quite sure how to do so.

I tried adding an if statement inside the foreach loop with a $counter which will show the embedded code when $counter is equal to $i, but I'm either doing it wrong or just don't know how to do it properly as nothing appears in the body, not the video nor the images..

Would appreciate all the help, thanks!

Here's the code:

page.php :

```
public function index($path = "")
{

    $data = $this->data;

        $images = [
            "images/portraits/1.jpg",
            "images/portraits/2.jpg",
            "images/portraits/3.jpg",
            "images/portraits/4.jpg"
        ];

    $data['images'] = $images;
    $counter = 0;
    $data['counter'] = $counter;
    return view($this->folderPath."main",$data);
}
```

main.blade.php :

```
    @foreach($images as $i)
       <?php if ($counter == 2)?>
         <?php if ($counter == 2) ?>
            <iframe
             width="560" height="315" 
            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/VIDEOID? 
            rel=0&amp;controls=0" 
            frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" 
            allowfullscreen>
            </iframe>
        <div class="cbp-item">
            <a href="{{$i}}" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    <img src="{{str_replace(".jpeg","_mini.jpeg",str_replace(".jpg","_mini.jpg",$i))}}" alt="">
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap cbp-gray">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <i class="fa fa-expand enlarge-icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: what've you tried so far? what is the actual problem you're having?

Comment: also, look at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp

Comment: @SérgioReis I tried adding an if statement inside the foreach loop with a $counter which will show the embedded code when $counter is equal to $i, but I'm either doing it wrong or just don't know how to do it properly as nothing appears in the body, not the video nor the images..

Comment: check @Nirali answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do somthing like this with your requirement

page.php :

```
public function index($path = "")
{

    $data = $this->data;

        $images = [
            ["type" => "image", "file" => "images/portraits/1.jpg"],
            ["type" => "image", "file" => "images/portraits/2.jpg"],
            ["type" => "image", "file" => "images/portraits/3.jpg"],
            ["type" => "video", "file" => "https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"]
        ];

    $data['images'] = $images;
    return view($this->folderPath."main",$data);
}
main.blade.php :

    @foreach($images as $i)
        <div class="cbp-item">
            <a href="{{$i['file']}}" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox">
                <div class="cbp-caption-defaultWrap">
                    @if($i['type'] == 'image')
                      <img src="{{str_replace(".jpeg","_mini.jpeg",str_replace(".jpg","_mini.jpg",$i['file']))}}" alt="">
                    @else
                      <iframe width="420" height="315"
src="{{ $i['file'] }}">
</iframe>
                    @endif
                </div>
                <div class="cbp-caption-activeWrap cbp-gray">
                    <div class="cbp-l-caption-alignCenter">
                        <div class="cbp-l-caption-body">
                            <i class="fa fa-expand enlarge-icon"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

Comment: I like this idea, but I'm getting 
"htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given (View: C:\Project\resources\views\clients\main.blade.php"

Comment: Can you find at which exact line you are getting the error?

Comment: I think issue is with your other view element because this above given blade file and controller is working for me without any syntax error.

Comment: One more thing you can pass view file name like this return view("clients.main",$data); instead of return view($this->folderPath."main",$data);

Comment: Apparently it's this line:
  <a href="<?php echo e($i['file']); ?>" class="cbp-caption cbp-lightbox">

Comment: Alright, not sure what I've done but I'm not getting the error anymore, BUT, now none of the images are showing, only the video.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168724/discussion-between-nirali-and-dor-golan).